# How to center align dynamic title action bar using java code in android?

Tags: android

I want to center align dynamic title in action bar using java code. My title is going to change every time depending upon String variable CoName. Please help me to make the title of ActionBar in center. Thanks in advance!

My android activity java code is:

```
public class BaseActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{

private static final int MENU_ITEM1 = 0;
private static final int MENU_ITEM2 = 1;
private static final int MENU_ITEM3 = 2;
private static final int Menu_ITEM4 = 3;
private ImageButton SalesButton;
private SharedPreferences SharedPreferences;
//private String UserName;
private TextView tv2;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.baseactivity);



     SharedPreferences =getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME,  LoginActivity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    CoName = SharedPreferences.getString("CONAME", null);
    Username = SharedPreferences.getString("USERNAME", null);


    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE); 
     getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.baseactivity);

     actionBar.setTitle(CoName);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {


    menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_ITEM1, Menu.NONE, Username);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.commonmenu, menu);
    //menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_ITEM2, Menu.NONE, "Setting");
    //menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_ITEM3, Menu.NONE, "Refresh");
    //menu.add(Menu.NONE, Menu_ITEM4, Menu.NONE,"Log Out");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId()) 
     {
        case MENU_ITEM1 :  
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked: Menu No. 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
        case R.id.menu2:
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked: Menu No. 2 ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;

        case R.id.menu3 :
        Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked: Menu No. 3 ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;

        case R.id.menu4:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);



        default:
               return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);    
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
try getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
```

instead of using

```
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
```